# What is the best alternative for an application with multiple accesses to the database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some client applications that will make several restfull calls per second to my Rails application.

My restful service will basically be, find a user by id and update their data. But this will be done many times per second.

I am studying sql-caching and background jobs, but as I have little experience I do not know if this would solve my problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alternatives to what?

Comment: @AndrewMarshallfor an application with multiple accesses to the database.I have a REST service that is used by several client applications and this REST service accesses the database.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I've studied sql caching and background jobs so clients do not expect the request. But I do not know if they are like better alternatives or if there is a simpler alternative.